# Xamarin Forms - UWP custom renderer: how to add a child to a stacklayout

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp

I'm trying to insert a UWP specific child in the custom renderer of a `StackLayout`.
However, in the sample code below, `Control` is always `null` whereas my `StackLayout` has Children. Maybe `StackPanel` is not what `StackLayout` is rendered into in UWP.

```
public class MyRenderer : ViewRenderer<StackLayout, StackPanel>
{
    private bool _childAdded;

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_childAdded && Control?.Children != null)
        {
            _childAdded = true;
            Control.Children.Insert(0, new Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle());
        }
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some modification in you are cade because you are calling **base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender,e)** after code implementation. Just try to use below code.

```
public class MyRenderer : ViewRenderer<StackLayout, StackPanel>
{
    private bool _childAdded;

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
         base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
         if(Control==null)
          return;
        if (!_childAdded && Control.Children != null)
        {
            _childAdded = true;
            Control.Children.Insert(0, new Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Tks, but I don't see how starting with the base implementation would change anything. However, you made me realise that this is not `Children` which is `null` but `Control`. Hence the issue is surely that the `StackLayout` implementation in UWP may not be `StackPanel`.

Answer (score 0):

The `StackLayout` (`Layout`) renderer is `ViewRenderer` and implemented on UWP by `FrameworkElement`; [Renderer Base Classes and Native Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/renderers).

Theoretical renderer:

```
public class MyRenderer : ViewRenderer<StackLayout, FrameworkElement>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

> Control is always null whereas my StackLayout has Children. Maybe StackPanel.

Derive from [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/custom#overview),

> In Xamarin.Forms, all layout classes derive from the [`Layout<T>`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/StackLayout.cs#L7) class and constrain the generic type to View and its derived types. But the layout of children element is incorrect.

And the match Native control within UWP platform is [`LayoutRenderer`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/LayoutRenderer.cs). So it is not inherit `StackPanel` directly. You could also custom a customrederer like the follow.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(StackLayout), typeof(ICustomStackLayoutRenderer))]

namespace CustomStackLayoutRenderer.UWP
{
    public class ICustomStackLayoutRenderer : ViewRenderer<StackLayout, StackPanel>
    {
        private bool _childAdded;
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<StackLayout> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control == null)
            {
                var stacklayout = new StackPanel();
                SetNativeControl(stacklayout);
            }
            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {

            }
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                if (!_childAdded && Control.Children != null)
                {
                    _childAdded = true;
                    Control.Children.Insert(0, new Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle() { Width = 100, Height = 100, Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red) });
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

For your requirement, the better way is that create a `CustomStackLayout` inherit `StackLayout` in `Xamarin.Forms`, and re-layout your children element in your `LayoutChildren` override method. For more detail you could refer [**Creating a Custom Layout**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/custom).